# Что лучше использовать для отправки данных на сервер

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, post

Что лучше использовать: отправку черезь Html form, или же в javascript перевести все данные в JSON и отправить на сервер post-ом?

Я знаю, что JS используют для валидации данных, но ведь через него тоже отправляют данные. В чем преимущество того или иного метода и какой лучше использовать для отправки однотипных данных? В каждом input будут лишь http-адреса.

Comment: Смотря что вам нужно. Есть вариант с перезагрузкой страницы или через AJAX. Никто не скажет, что лучше или хуже. Везде есть свои недостатки и преимущества.

Comment: то есть через формы - это с перезагрузкой? я имею ввиду, что можно ли через формы, но без перезагрузки?

Comment: да. Через формы можно с помощью AJAX. У jQuery есть функция для сериализации данных формы -  http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @korytoff оформите как полноценный ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенесено из комментариев:

Смотря что вам нужно. Есть вариант с перезагрузкой страницы или через AJAX. Никто не скажет, что лучше или хуже. Везде есть свои недостатки и преимущества.

Что бы отправить форму без перезагрузки страницы можно воспользоваться [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) из библиотеки [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) { // добавляем событие на отправку формы
    e.preventDefault(); // блокируем отправку формы по умолчанию
    $.ajax({
      method: $(this).attr('method'), // метод запроса берем из атрибутов
      url: $(this).attr('action'), // адрес запроса берем из атрибутов
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $(this).serialize(), // данные для запроса берем из формы
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response); // успех
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log(response); // ошибка запроса
      }
    });
    return false; // так же блокируем отправку формы (по моему для старых браузеров), не обязательно, можно только e.preventDefault()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/myscript.php">
  <input type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Подготовка данных из формы для запроса делается с помощью метода [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).